# AWS Lambda layers size exceed issue upon consecutive build

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-lambda, serverless

I am deploying my code to AWS Lambda using Serverless Framework. I am using GitHub Actions for my CI/CD pipeline. I am also using Lambda Layers for storing my dependencies. The pipeline is successfully creating the new lambda function and lambda layers, but upon consecutive builds, I am getting this error in the pipeline

```
 An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the PublishLayerVersion operation: Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes
```

But there hasn't been any change in the size of the dependency zip and also my function zip size is 1,023.6 kB.

I have tried deleting the existing version of the layer and then redeploying it, but I was still getting the same error.

Comment: Be sure to note the unzipped size of the layer(s) and your function, and not the size of the .zip file itself. Also, check your CI/CD pipeline and make sure it isn't including dependencies in layers that it may not need.

Answer (score 0):

First of check the size of lambda layer that the lambda function is using. A lambda function can only handle layer of size 256 mb. If you are using multiple lambda layer, then due to this the size must have exceed than the threshold.